# infinite permutation - auto composition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

Identity permutation (infinite): 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31... 
Permutation $\sigma$ (https://oeis.org/A233279): 
1  2  3  4  5  7  6  8  9 11 10 15 14 12 13 16 17 19 18 23 22 20 21 31 30 28 29 24 25 27 26...
$\sigma^2$:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 13 12 15 14 16 17 18 19 21 20 23 22 26 27 24 25 31 30 29 28...
$\sigma^4$:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31...
and so on:
$$\forall m ≥ 0, \forall n > 0 \mbox{ such that }  n < 2^{m+1}, \mbox{ one has }  \sigma^{(2^m)}(n) = n$$
Does anyone know how this kind of 'limit' or 'convergence' or ... is called, or any reference?

Comment: The infinite permutation is itself a composition of finite-range permutations, each working within a closed interval of $2^m+1$ to  $2^{m+1}$ (or equivalent). Within each of these intervals the maximum orbit is also a multiple of any smaller orbits leading to the identity permutation for a maximum-orbit composition of the finite-range permutation.